# Angular - re-fire http?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

Sometimes in my application a HTTP call to get a list or some sort of resource will fail for no obvious reason, however, if it's re-fired straight away it will work.

Is there a way to configure all HTTP calls to say something along the lines of

```
if ( has no success after 2-3 seconds ) {   
   re-fire HTTP call...
}
```

I find in my application (which is ASP.NET) that often times I have to double click a link to make a page load. This I feel is probably the same issue with the HTTP calls in the code. Not sure as to how to trace or de-bug this sort of problem and if anyone had any thoughts on that you would really be helping me out!

Any advice much would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to change the behaviour of the $http service in Angular, then there is a way. [This post describes it briefly](https://www.exratione.com/2013/08/angularjs-wrapping-http-for-fun-and-profit/), and here's the important bits citated from the post.:

> For example if you are making a late global alteration to a large
>   ongoing project, or want to change the behavior of XHR requests in
>   third party code that can't be altered. In these circumstances you
>   might use $provide.decorator() to globally replace $http with a
>   wrapped version.

By wrapping the $http servie you have the option to change behaviour.

*It sounds like you have a different problem though since you need to trigger calls twice, I suggest you solve that first.*

Comment: Thanks a mil, had a look at that post really interesting. Going to try it out once I get a chance today.

Comment: And also, a tip can be to use the developer tools in your browser. Press F12 for Chrome to open it. By using the network tab in the developer tools you can see the trafic and calls your browser is doing to the server. See if some calls get stuck or has strange response codes.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using an `$httpInterceptor`, maybe a god solution could be fix the problem instead of that, by the way, there is an example:

> [this wonderful post maybe help you to understand $http interceptors](http://onehungrymind.com/winning-http-interceptors-angularjs/)

```js
(function(window, angular, APP) {
  var MAX_ERRORS = 1; // after that: giving up
  
  function FeelAgainConfig($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function FeelAgainInterceptor($q, $http) {
      var interceptors = {};
      
      interceptors.responseError = function FeelAgainInterceptorResponseError(data) {
        // implement an error counter that helps you to not fall in an infinite call stack
        if(data.errorCount >= MAX_ERRORS) {
          return $q.reject(data);
        };
        
        // Perform the request again;
        
      };
      
      return interceptors;
    });
  }
  
  APP
    .config(FeelAgainConfig)
  ;
})(window, window.angular, window.angular.module('feelAgain$http', []));
```

Comment: Thanks so much, going to take a look at this once I get time.